# Change the fontSize in all TextField's in MUI v5 via theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have found that I can change the fontSize on a single TextField by passing something like

```
<TextField
  InputProps={{
    style: { fontSize: '0.8rem' },
  }}
/>
```

I can make a similar change via the theme API like

```
MuiTextField: {
        defaultProps: {
          InputProps: {
            style: { fontSize: '0.8rem' },
          },
        },
      },
```

however, any TextField that overrides InputProps will not get this fontSize change. Is there any way to more deeply override it?

Answer (score 1):

You should do the style overrides using the `styleOverrides` feature of the theme rather than via `defaultProps`.

Here's a working example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "& .MuiInputBase-root, & .MuiInputLabel-root": {
            fontSize: "0.8rem"
          },
          "& .MuiInputLabel-root.MuiInputLabel-shrink": {
            // With the smaller font size, the shrink effect
            // shouldn't go quite as high ("-6px" instead of "-9px")
            // in order for it to look correct.
            transform: "translate(14px, -6px) scale(0.75)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
export default function BasicTextFields() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit TextField styleOverrides]

Comment: thanks for sharing this answer, indeed styleOverrides is a better approach. I will also just add for the record, i just ended up changing the entire theme.typography.fontSize to be smaller, rather than just one component. this had the effect of changing textfield font sizes and everything else. I started trying to change elements piecemeal but it seemed better to try this global approach